# Image rendering on Retina displays in grayscale

Tags: image, browser, retina-display

On our custom developed e-commerce website, we are using big images to show high quality pictures of the products to be sold. When these images are rendered on **Retina displays** (as well as on Microsoft Surface machines), while loading, they first appear as black-and-white images, before snapping into color. (Using network throttling, it is easier to reproduce.) We're having this on the latest versions of **Safari, Firefox and Chrome**. I'm wondering if this could be due to the browser deciding to show some grayscale-data it already has downloaded, so the end-user sees something as fast as possible.

So in other words, do browsers show black-and-white versions of images first if those images are downloading slowly?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes :-)

More information can be found [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51933/how-does-this-image-interleave-from-grayscale-to-color)
In short, we were using sequential JPEGs which were bigger for Retina screens. Being bigger, those images loaded slower, so most browser show the black-and-white layer of the YCbCr layers first, then the first color layer, then the second. Exception to this rule is f.i. IE11 (see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2013/09/12/using-hardware-to-decode-and-load-jpg-images-up-to-45-faster-in-internet-explorer-11/)).

We solved this issue by using progressive JPEGs instead of sequential ones.